# Pandas get multiple first occurrences of each group

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the multiple first occurrences of each group (ie: every time a group appears after another group), given that some groups may appear more than once in the data frame. For example:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| **AAA** | **111** |
| AAA | 222 |
| AAA | 444 |
| **BBB** | **111** |
| BBB | 333 |
| **CCC** | **777** |
| CCC | 333 |
| **AAA** | **888** |
| AAA | 777 |

I would like to return both "first" occurrences of the group AAA:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| AAA | 111 |
| BBB | 111 |
| CCC | 777 |
| AAA | 888 |

I've tried using groupby but it only returns the first occurrence after grouping. Is there a simple way to get this kind of result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) on a custom group:

```
df.groupby(df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift()).cumsum(), as_index=False).first()
```

output:

```
  col1  col2
0  AAA   111
1  BBB   111
2  CCC   777
3  AAA   888
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
One more question on this strategy: how could I apply the same logic, but for two columns at the same time?
Currently, I am using

df.groupby(['ColA', 'ColB']).first()

and I would like to apply this same logic you have suggested. Would it be possible as well?

Comment: use `df[['ColA', 'ColB']].ne(df[['ColA', 'ColB']].shift()).all(1).cumsum()` as group (or `any` instead of `all` is any difference should start a new group)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
df[df['col1'].ne(df['col1'].shift())]
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `itertools` -

```py
from itertools import groupby
firsts = []
for k, v in groupby(df.to_records(), key=lambda x: x[1]):
    first, *rest = v
    firsts.append(first)
pd.DataFrame.from_records(firsts, columns=df.reset_index().columns, index='index')
```

**Output**

```
      col1  col2
index           
0      AAA   111
3      BBB   111
5      CCC   777
7      AAA   888
```